# Have you ever written a header without guards?

Tags: c++, header, standards, header-files

I am wondering why C++ compilers don't generate header guards automatically for headers?

```
// Why do I have to write this for every .hpp file I create?!!
#ifndef myheader_hpp__
#define myheader_hpp__
// ...
#endif
```

I haven't met a situation where they aren't needed when I write my headers. I can't see a real use-case of the opposite behavior, but I would be glad to see one. Is there a technical difficulty or is it just history?!

Comment: C and C++ try not to make assumptions about what you're trying to do with the language.

Comment: Are you aware of #pragma once?

Comment: @Cliff Yes I am aware of `#pragma` once, but I prefer to do it the standard way even if it is more verbose. Anyway, why do we need to tell the compiler something it has to do(as I see it)!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are [some preprocessor tricks that require the same header included multiple times into the same compilation unit](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/Preprocessor#X-Macros).  [Another reference.](http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184401387)

Besides that, most compilers do allow you to shorten all of that down to:

```
#pragma once
```

Comment: Thanks, that's an interesting use-case.

Comment: Since you evoke preprocessor tricks, you could also give the example of Boost.Preprocessor, that allows vertical repetition through file iteration (i.e. successive inclusion of the same file). More information in [this introduction](http://www.boostpro.com/mplbook/preprocessor.html).

Comment: First part is good answer. Though I can't agree with recommending `#pragma once` as it is non-standard.

Comment: @LucTouraille: That looks exactly like the X-Macros I've linked to.  Boost is a relatively new user of this trick, and doesn't do a particularly good job explaining it, so I don't know why it would rate special mention.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: fair enough, I just thought it would be interesting to link to a library actually making use of such trick.

Answer (score 2):

To a compiler, automatically putting in include guards isn't truly practical. You can define prototypes for methods/functions/classes/etc without running into problems, and this is usually done in a header. When a class is defined in a header, though, you run into the problem of having the class defined more than once by the compiler if it is included by two different .cpp files or other headers.

Really, include guards are just one trick for headers. You don't *always* need them, and there are some cases where you wouldn't use them. This is actually easier, believe it or not.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a general purpose mechanism to insert one file into another.

It's just that general purpose ability is used for a very common specific purpose in 99% of the cases.

Answer (score 2):

I'll simply point you to the Clang / LLVM project.

In this project, they created a way to encode data using a simple descriptive language, that is then fed up to a tool (called tblgen for Table Generator) that is meant to produce a C++ file. For example, [the diagnostics](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/include/clang/Basic/DiagnosticSemaKinds.td):

```
let Component = "Sema" in {
let CategoryName = "Semantic Issue" in {

// Constant expressions
def err_expr_not_ice : Error<
  "expression is not an integer constant expression">;

....
```

There are a few thousands diagnostics in Clang, separated in several files. Once processed by tblgen, they will generate a huge `.inc` file which, for each diagnostic, will contain a macro call. By defining the macro and including the file, you can produce a [C++ table](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/Basic/DiagnosticIDs.cpp) (or anything else really, but the use is generally for tables):

```
static const StaticDiagInfoRec StaticDiagInfo[] = {
#define DIAG(ENUM,CLASS,DEFAULT_MAPPING,DESC,GROUP,               \
             SFINAE,ACCESS,NOWERROR,SHOWINSYSHEADER,              \
             CATEGORY,BRIEF,FULL)                                 \
  { diag::ENUM, DEFAULT_MAPPING, CLASS, SFINAE, ACCESS,           \
    NOWERROR, SHOWINSYSHEADER, CATEGORY,                          \
    STR_SIZE(#ENUM, uint8_t), STR_SIZE(GROUP, uint8_t),           \
    STR_SIZE(DESC, uint16_t), STR_SIZE(BRIEF, uint16_t),          \
    STR_SIZE(FULL, uint16_t),                                     \
    #ENUM, GROUP, DESC, BRIEF, FULL },
#include "clang/Basic/DiagnosticCommonKinds.inc"
#include "clang/Basic/DiagnosticDriverKinds.inc"
#include "clang/Basic/DiagnosticFrontendKinds.inc"
#include "clang/Basic/DiagnosticLexKinds.inc"
#include "clang/Basic/DiagnosticParseKinds.inc"
#include "clang/Basic/DiagnosticASTKinds.inc"
#include "clang/Basic/DiagnosticSemaKinds.inc"
#include "clang/Basic/DiagnosticAnalysisKinds.inc"
#undef DIAG
  { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
};
```

And the same files can produce different tables, since you are free to write the macros as you wish.

It is, of course, a very specific use.

But don't worry, even though the modules didn't make it into C++11, we can hope for C++1x.